# Is there a way to use configService in App.Module.ts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am building RESTful service with NestJs, I have followed the [example](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) to build configurations for different environments. It works well for most code. However I am wondering if I can use it in my `app.module.ts`?

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      host: `${config.get('mongo_url') || 'localhost'}`,
      port: 27017,
      username: 'a',
      password: 'b',
      database: 'my_db',
      entities: [__dirname + '/MyApp/*.Entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true}),
    MyModule,
    ConfigModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [MyService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As you can see I do want to move the MongoDb Url info outside the code and I am thinking to leverage `.env` files. But after some attempts, it does not seem to work.

Of course I can use `${process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'localhost'}` instead, and set the environment variables. I'm still curious if I can make the `configService` work.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to use a [dynamic import](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#custom-connection-factory) (see *Async configuration*). With it, you can inject dependencies and use them for the initialization:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'mongodb',
    host: configService.databaseHost,
    port: configService.databasePort,
    username: configService.databaseUsername,
    password: configService.databasePassword,
    database: configService.databaseName,
    entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: true,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

Comment: thanks, dude, this is exactly what I needed! (:

Comment: Why must use `inject` into it ?

Comment: @soroush configService is a dependency that will be used to resolve to env variables and passed to typeorm, so nest is passing the configService into the usefactory so it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use MongooseModule function from the same package for config and properties as given below:

```
 MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    uri: `mongodb://${configService.get(
      'MONGODB_USERNAME',
    )}:${configService.get('MONGODB_PASSWORD')}@${configService.get(
      'MONGODB_HOST',
    )}:27017/nest?authSource=admin`,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```